# how do I configure webpack to define a "placeholder" module in which to inject a dependency after the build is done?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, webpack, uglifyjs, emscripten

(I've posted on GitHub as well: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2082)

I have a dependency on a library that is generated by [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), and I'd like to bundle it alongside the library I'm building. However, I can't figure out how to configure webpack to do what I want, which is to bundle all of my modules / dependencies and uglify the result, except without touching the emscripten-generated library.

I want webpack to leave the emscripten-generated library alone, and the reason is, it looks like this:

[image: emscripten-generated library]

In other words, it is highly optimized `asm.js` JavaScript, compiled from C++, and it's already uglified; it doesn't need to be parsed (I know about `module.noParse`). Unfortunately, my current `webpack.config.js` bundles and uglifies everything, including the emscripten-generated library.

Is there a way to bundle and uglify everything, using a "placeholder" module for the emscripten-generated library, and then inject it as the last step?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `exclude` property in the UglifyJsPlugin config?